# Symfony 2 - Access mapped Object property form twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I hava a entity with the following flied:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Document", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $image;
```

which I get with the following method:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('airpaprcms2Bundle:Post')
            ->findByPageType(1);

    if (!$posts) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No posts in Database!');
    }

    return $this->render('airpaprcms2Bundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('posts' => $posts));
}
```

How can I access a property of the mapped object form within twig? I tried `post.image.file` (the mapped entity Document has a property file)

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div>
    <h1>
        <a href="{{ path('_view', {'slug': post.slug}) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h1>
    <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
    <img src="{{ post.image.name }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and get the following error message:

```
Item "file" for "" does not exist in airpaprcms2Bundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 11
```

What is the right syntax to access the mapped document property?

Comment: can you show us your method witch return this twig? Did you try {{ post.image }} alone? To see if you image entity is loaded with your post

Comment: Updated my question. If I use `{{ post.image }}`, I get the following error message: (Can't cast to string) `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\Entity\Document could not be converted to string in Default:index.html.twig at line 12.`

Comment: Done. Hope it helps. I guess it's some really dumb mistake on my side ...

Comment: I think one of your post is not linked to an image, look at the error it's telling you that he can't find the item file for nothing. Can you do a var_dump of your $posts in your controller and check that every post as a link to your image object?

Comment: That was it! There was one post without a mapping to a image entity. Thanks a lot for your help! Do you want to write it down as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the property of your linked entity with the following twig syntax:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.entityName.propertyName }}
{% endfor %}
```

In your case that would be:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.image.propertyName }}
{% endfor %}
```

Be sure to check that **all** post entities are linked to an image object. If one post entity has no link to an image, you will get a property not found error when trying to render your page.

Comment: Or you can just test that your object is well related to your other object before render it in twig ;) glad it help !