# Symfony 2 - Twig can't access to correct mapped entity objects

Tags: php, symfony, entity, twig, template-engine

I'm new with Symfony

There is a simple method indexAction in my controller class:

```
    function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager();

        $prods = $em->getRepository('EcommerceProductBundle:ProductData')->findBy(array('product'=>2));

        return $this->render('EcommerceProductBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
            'prods' => $prods
        )); 
    }
```

It seems that works good in fact there are the queries visible in the Profiles and the Entities are well retrieved.

```
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductData  Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductData  Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\Product  Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\Language     Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductImage     Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\FileImage    Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\Product  Valid
Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\Language     Valid
```

According with this same post
[Symfony 2 - Access mapped Object property form twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818519/symfony-2-access-mapped-object-property-form-twig)

I tried to call in my twig template (index.html.twig) an object of the *Product* entity like below

```
{% for prod in prods %}
    Price: {{ prod.Product.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

and it works right.
Not the same happen if i try to call an object of the *ProductImage* entity like below

```
{% for prod in prods %}
    Image title: prod.ProductImage.title
or

    {% for pimg in prod.ProductImage %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error:

```
Method "ProductImage" for object "Ecommerce\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductData" does not exist in EcommerceProductBundle:Page:index.html.twig at line 36
```

The *ProductImage Entity* is correctly mapped like the *Product Entity*, why the last one work perfectly on the contrary of the first one?

Comment: from the linked example: "Be sure to check all did post-entities are linked to an image object. If one entity post has no link to an image, you want to get a property not found error when trying to render your page." Show us your ProductData and Product entities.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved calling the object in ProductData that point to the ProductImage Entity.

snippet of *ProductData* Entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductImage", mappedBy="product_pi", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id"),
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="language_id")
 * })
 */
protected $products_pi;
```

snippet of *index.html.twig* template

```
{% for pimg in prod.getProductsPi %}
 {{ pimg.title }}
{% endfor %}
```